# Unity can a trigger collider activate OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, collider

As the title says: can a trigger collider of an object trigger the "OnCollisionEnter" function of antoher object with a normal collider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. The `OnCollisionEnter` function won't be called when one collider is normal and the other is trigger. If you're seeing something different on your side then it's a bug.

Although, this is possible when you want to do the opposite with `OnTriggerEnter` but one of the colliders must have `Rigidbody` attached to it for `OnTriggerEnter` to be called. It doesn't matter which one.

Take a look at the Collision action matrix from the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) or the image below for scenarios in which `OnCollisionEnter` would be called:

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, I'll see which is the best way for my case.